# Firebase CLI v11.1.0 is incompatible with Node.js v16.1.0

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-shell, google-source-repositories

I am using **Google Cloud Shell Editor** to run my **Firebase+React** application.
When I run Firebase CLI i got this:

> Firebase CLI v11.1.0 is incompatible with Node.js v16.1.0 Please upgrade Node.js to version ^14.18.0 || >=16.4.0

If I update

```
npm install -g firebase-tools
```

I got this

> Firebase CLI v11.2.0 is incompatible with Node.js v16.1.0 Please upgrade Node.js to version ^14.18.0 || >=16.4.0

Answer (score 1):

Run the command line below

```
nvm install 16.4.0
```

And it works for me ;-)

[image]

Comment: 'nvm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: NVM is a node version manager. Allow you to install many versions. To use firebase tools with Node v16 then you need to try `npm install -g firebase-tools@12`

Answer (score 0):

i used `npm i -g firebase-tools@12.9.1` its compatible with node 16.14.0.
that works for me